# How to set tags for AWS EC2 instance in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, botocore

I am new to `Boto3`, and wanted to create a VPC, subnets, and some ec2 instances. The basic architecture is having a VPC, 2 subnets within 2 different availability zones (us-east-1a and b), and applying a security group which allows `SSH` and `ping`.

My problem is how to specify **additional options** for each resources. The Python SDK (unlike how `Javadoc` works) doesn't show the required arguments and example options, so I'm confused.

How can I specify `tags` for resources? (e.g. ec2 instance). I need to set `name`, `owner`, etc.

```
instances2 = ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-095575c1a372d21db', InstanceType='t2.micro', MaxCount=1, MinCount=1, NetworkInterfaces=[{'SubnetId': subnet2.id, 'DeviceIndex': 0, 'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True, 'Groups': [sec_group.group_id]}])
instances2[0].wait_until_running()
print(instances1[0].id)
```

Comment: The questions you are asking can be easily answered by simply looking at the documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `TagSpecifications` argument with `'ResourceType'` set to `'instance'`:

```
TagSpecifications=[
    {
      'ResourceType': 'instance',
      'Tags': [
        {
          'Key': 'name',
          'Value': 'foobar'
        },
        {
          'Key': 'owner',
          'Value': 'me'
        },
      ]
    },
  ],
```

It is in the docs but you do need to know what you're looking for...

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I'm new to AWS SDK. So this `TagSpecifications` comes as an argument inside the `ec2.create_instances()`?

Answer (score 3):

Following works for me with python 3.7 and boto3 1.12.39

Reference - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=create_instances#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances

```
    AMI = os.environ['AMI']
    INSTANCE_TYPE = os.environ['INSTANCE_TYPE']
    KEY_NAME = os.environ['KEY_NAME']
    SUBNET_ID = os.environ['SUBNET_ID']    

    TAG_SPEC = [
        {
        "ResourceType":"instance",
        "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "EC2_INSTANCE_TEST_AUTOGENERATED"
                }
            ]
    }
    ]

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

    instance = ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId = AMI,
        InstanceType = INSTANCE_TYPE,
        KeyName = KEY_NAME,
        SubnetId = SUBNET_ID,
        TagSpecifications = TAG_SPEC,
        MaxCount = 1,
        MinCount = 1
        )
```