# How to set availability zone in Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, boto

Putting it simple: I created an AWS subnet with `boto3` with the following simple one-liner script, but how can I set availability zone for my subnet?

```
subnet1 = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock='10.0.0.0/24')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the argument `AvailabilityZone='eu-west-1a',` for example.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_subnet

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure what that string should exactly be. Since regions already specified, thought maybe we should just say `a`, instead of `us-east-1a`!

Comment: My other question for you for setting tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436835/how-to-set-tags-for-aws-ec2-instance-in-boto3?noredirect=1#comment91816805_52436835